# Hide Activity Indicator when firebase authentication redirects to recapcha window (iOS - Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented a Phone Authentication in my iOS app using Firebase, In that case, I have added an activity indicator to show a loading window. But, in some cases a ReCaptcha appears and, since the activity indicator is still in the window, the ReCaptcha cannot be completed, which makes the app freeze in one state.

Below is my code for login:

```
let activityIndicator = EAActivityIndicator()
activityIndicator.show()
    
Auth.auth().languageCode = "en"
    
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(mobileNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { verificationId, error in
        
    activityIndicator.hide()
        
    if let error = error {
        // handle error
    } else {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController(), animated: true)
    }
}
```

As in the code, I show an activity indicator when the login button is tapped, if the mobile number is correct and if a 6 digit code is sent it will redirect to the Code entering View Controller. In certain cases, a ReCaptcha appears, but since the activity indicator is still on the screen, the ReCaptcha cannot be completed.

Screenshots:
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: try to hide loader inside DispatchQueue.main.async {}

Comment: @KaushikMakwana How to know if the ReCaptcha window is open? there is no completion handler for that. But we can do something through uiDelegate parameter. Do u have any idea?

Comment: What delegate parameters does the Activity indicator have?

Comment: @AzeemMuzammil For Disable reCAPTCHA Authentication Go and Enabling Background Modes capability Inside of the Background Modes and check "Remote Notification" checkbox.

Comment: @VisalRajapakse there are no delegate parameter for activity indicator, the firebase login method has uiDelegate parameter, which can be used to customize reCapcha window.

Comment: @KaushikMakwana I have done that, but when I run on emulators or on devices while app background refresh is turned off, the reCapcha is used instead of silence push notification.

Comment: By the looks of it, your `ActivityIndicator` is added to the `UIWindow` rather than the `UIViewController`. Try so see if you can alter where the `ActivityIndicator` is shown

Comment: @VisalRajapakse yeah bro, you are correct. Thank you man...